# Function that iterates for each item in a list

Tags: python, list, function, loops

Here I've created a list of websites that I want to run through a function.

```
import requests

item_ids=[11732, 536]
url_template = 'http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/include/gecgraphjson.php?jsid=%r'
your_sites = []

for i in range(0, len(item_ids)):
    result = url_template % item_ids[i]
    your_sites.append(result)
```

The tricky part (for me, anyway) is creating a function that takes each item in `your_sites` and iterates it through the function. I thought about using some kind of for loop, but I wasn't sure how to implement it and thought that there might be a more efficient way anyhow. Here's my try, which returns `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

```
def data_grabber(): 
    for i in range(0, len(your_sites)): 
        url = your_sites[i]
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'Referer': 'www.grandexchangecentral.com'})
        data = r.json
        prices = [i[1] for i in data]
```

I'd like it to return `prices` for each website, but I can only get errors and None values for my efforts. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: "Running a list through a function" is a prime usage case for a list comprehension.

Comment: (1) Please fix the indentation in your function `data_grabber`. (2) Post a full traceback please so that we can take a look at exactly what's causing this error

Comment: are you looking for map()? http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: I'm very sorry about that, I fixed the indentation. The error I get is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in data_grabber
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: For "some kind of for loop": `for url in your_sites: doStuff(url)`. You can't get any simpler than that. However, more often than not, you're better off with a list comprehension instead of an explicit loop.

Comment: The error is happening because it's trying to create the `prices` list, but `data` is `None`. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13169263/432913) answer is telling you that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make `your_sites` a global variable, it's really easy to pass it as a parameter. You don't need an explicit index for `for` loops, just iterate the object you are interested in. When you *do* need an explicit index, use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
def data_grabber(your_sites): 
    for url in your_sites: 
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'Referer': 'www.grandexchangecentral.com'})
        data = r.json   # if r.json None the next line will fail
        prices = [i[1] for i in data]
```

Not sure what you want to do if `r.json` is none. You could try something like this

```
        data = r.json or []
```